# C# returns "C:\Windows\Sysnative" as invalid directory but python does not

Tags: python, c#

I need to run a command to disable some checks.
I am really wondering same logic works on python but in C# it throws error.

When i switches the directory to Sysnative in C# it throws error like invalid directory but in python it works fine.

Please find the code and help me with suggestion to solve this error.

C# code: This returns invalid directory

```
string dir = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative";
string command = "bcdedit.exe /set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS";
directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir);
Console.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}: Disabling integrity check!");
Process integrityCheck = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
         FileName = "cmd.exe",
         Arguments = @"/K " + command,
         Verb = "runas",
         UseShellExecute = false,
         RedirectStandardOutput = false
    }
};
try
{
    integrityCheck.Start();
    Console.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}: Disabled integrity check!");
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}: InvalidOperationException occured while disabling integrity check!!");
     Console.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}: {ioe.Message}");
}
finally
{
     integrityCheck.Close();
     Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(directory);
}
```

Python code: It executes the code without any error.

```
def disable_integrity_test():

cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r"C:\Windows\Sysnative")
command = "bcdedit.exe /set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS"

print("disable_integrity_test: %s" %(command))
subprocess.call(command)
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Comment: `os.chdir` might just swallow an invalid directory without complaint.

Comment: Why are you running `cmd` rather than `bcdedit` directly?

Comment: @mjwills Yes i can do that but just for my convenient used command prompt. It makes difference?

Comment: @mjwills thank you so much for the suggestion. I replaced cmd with bcdedit and it worked for me. I haven't thought this makes difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing "cmd.exe" with "bcdedit.exe" has solved my problem.

Thank you @mjwills for the suggestion.